# how do i detect what div/body is scrolling

Tags: jquery

Hello Stackoverflow peoples,

Im trying to change the background color on scroll, which is pretty simple, but not working for the fact that whatever wrapper i use to on the scroll doesnt work, I.E.

```
$('#whatever').scroll(function(){
    //magic
});
```

my current code: 
jsfiddle.net/SM3H9/7

can someone please help me decipher this mystery? I admit i havent touched jquery for a few months so i've gotten a bit rusty, but a bit of searching (stackoverflow, jquery web & google) doesnt seem to give me an answer.

Thank you stackoverflow peoples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach `scroll` to the element that is being scrolled. In your case the scroll comes from `html` element, but you attach the `scroll` event to div with class `mainContainer` that doesn't scroll.

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/SM3H9/8/

Comment: hmmn, apparently that works in the jsfiddle but not in my whole page code... how do i check what is scrolling?

Comment: you just need to attach `jQuery UI` to animate `backgroundColor`, here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SM3H9/9/) of @jsalonen

Comment: im using jquery.color to animate backgroundColor instead of the overpowered jquery.UI

Comment: hmmn..apparently you changed the .container css to scroll and that was what made it work....Thanks for the help!

Comment: Indeed. You need to attach the scroll event to the right element and ALSO make sure that the element actually does have a scrollbar ;)